# Is this sentence proper grammar?

Tags: grammar

Here's the sentence: "I'm going to stab the next person if he or she invites me to play 'Who will be your Valentine' again."

Is proper grammar being used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's an awkward construction.

This statement is filled with hyperbole and not meant to be taken literally (you're not actually going to stab anyone, are you?). Even so, putting the "next person" together with the "if" conditional conjunction does not seem natural. What if the condition never materialises, i.e. no one invites you to play the game? In that case, you're never actually going to "stab the next person" are you?

Better: "I'm going to stab the next person **who** invites me to play 'Who will be your Valentine' again."

You can also replace "who" with "that".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and suggestion! I appreciate it.